# Hosting company will not allow Office 365 SMTP connection to send emails. What are possible solutions?

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, office365, smtp-auth

For our domain(mydomain.com) , we have an Office 365 account that takes care of emails and the website is hosted with a hosting company on a shared server. From my shared server Laravel App I was sending emails using the office 365 SMTP server. The hosting company now blocks this connection to office 365 SMTP server:

"Please note that your account is hosted on a shared server where outgoing SMTP connections are restricted. This is to protect the reputation of the server IP address and prevent potential spamming.
You canconsider upgrading to a cloud server plan"

I do not wish to upgrade to a cloud server plan, are there any other options for an SMTP server ? , that my Laravel app could use ? I have a reseller account with many cpanel accounts on the shared server. So i could use another one of my domains smtp server but I need the emails sent out to be from an office 365 email address. So contact@mydomain.com. Possible solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending emails, its actually not recommended to use the SMTP server used by your normal email provider (e.g. Office 365, GMail).

Instead you should use a transactional email service, which is designed for sending a large number of emails programically.

See:

- [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/)
- [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/)

If you are unable to send emails using a particular port (which seems to be your issue), feel free to send emails user their respective API's:

- Sendgird:
  https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/api-getting-started/
  and https://sendgrid.com/docs/api-reference/
- Amazon SES: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-api.html

This will still use the usual HTTP ports, and use different ip's, therefore bypass any port & ip restrictions when sending emails.